# Hibernate: transactional insert and unit testing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I'm writing a unit test for a DAO call to insert a record into the DB using Hibernate.

It's transactional and I used @Transactional in that way:

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/spring-servlet.xml"})
@Transactional
public class MyDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao dao;

    @Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void testAddEmployee() {


        // Create some data (line 1)

        dao.addPerson(newPerson); // (line 2)

        // Query DB (line 3)

        // Check result (line 4)
    } // (line 5)
}
```

In the above code, the operation is committed only when the function terminates at line 5.

The fact is that at line 3 and 4 I need to query the DB to check if the instert has been completed succesfully. But I can't do that because my data is still not persisted.

What can I do in order to test this insert? Is there a way to commit before the end of the function?

I'm adding some more info here. This is the console output:

```
Hibernate: select person0_.ID as ID1_, person0_.NAME as NAME1_ from PERSON person0_
Hibernate: insert into PERSON (NAME) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select person0_.ID as ID1_, person0_.NAME as NAME1_ from PERSON person0_
```

For testing I'm using JUnit

Comment: try adding @TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true) in the test class level. by line 3 data should be available to query from DB

Comment: I tried to add this annotation, but it still doesn't work. Keep committing after the function ends

Comment: by line 3 data should be available to query from persisted object , Way of verifying is dao.addPerson(newPerson);
int testId = newPerson.getAppId();Assert.assertEquals(1, testId);

Comment: Reason is, Hibernate keep attach the object to session which is in persisted state, so any query to the object will return you the id assigned by auto increment strategy you have used

Comment: getId() would be a solution to create a test for insert. But in this case... what about delete?

Comment: Here you go: Please follow this blog entry which has a sample junit test cases for save and delete scenario. Please see the section 6 for more details. In simple word, when you are deleting a object, immediate below line load/find the object and check for assertNull http://blog.paxcel.net/blog/implementing-junit-in-spring-and-hibernate-apps/

Comment: That's a matter of choice how realistic should your test be. I prefer storing object id,  calling flush and clear on the hibernate session  UoW and then loading it back by id, all within a single transaction that's then rolled back. Imho Session.flush() is crucial, not the commit itself.

Comment: So doing flush and clear you effectively the same as if it were different transactions, because of the transaction isolation. When the session UoW is cleared it will fetch the objects back from the db when you call get() as if it was a new sesion.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test the insertion, you can use the following assertion:

```
Assert.assertNotNull(dao.findById(newPerson.getId()));
```

For deletion check, you can try the following test:

```
@Test
public void testDelete(){
    ...
    dao.removePerson(person);
    Assert.assertNull(dao.findById(person.getId()));
}
```